# Large Delimiters

Tags: delimiters

I am stuck with a LaTeX glitch! I am making an exercise on sequences and series. I have to write down an expression for the general form of a sequence for which I need large delimiters. I tried various ways but it did not work.

Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass[a4, 14pt]{extarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \[ \left{
       \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}
    \right}_{n=1}^{\infty}
 \]
 \end{align}

\end{document}
```

I tried `$$ .... $$`, `\[ ... \]`, and `\begin{align} ... \end{align}` but all returned errors on compiling. I don't know how to fix this!

Comment: You have to use `\left\{` instead of `\left{`. Also, use `\right\}` instead of `\right}`.

Answer (score 7):

You should type `\left\{` and `\right\}` instead of `\left{` and `\right{`, since `{` is a special symbol of TeX.